# Azure Pipeline Get Template name from variable

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Please consider the following:

```
- job: Backend
   steps:
    
    - template: $(ClassLibraryTemplate)
      parameters:
        projectName: 'Core'
        solutionPath: 'Source/Core.sln'
```

`ClassLibraryTemplate` is defined as a pipeline variable. But when I run the build, it fails because the variable is not replaced by its value and the template is not found.

Is it not possible to store the template name in a variable ?

Comment: I don't think that template path can be fetched from variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Azure DevOps YAML pipeline, the template get processed at compile time. However, the $(ClassLibraryTemplate) get processed at the runtime. That's why it fails.

More information: [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

You could define variable or parameter in your YAML pipeline, then use template expression. For parameter, you could specify value when queue/run pipeline in pop-up window.

For example:

```
parameters:
- name: temName
  displayName: template name
  type: string
  default: steps/test.yml


trigger:
  - none

variables:
- name: tem
  value: steps/build.yml 

jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - template: ${{ variables.tem }} 
  - template: ${{ parameters.temName }}
```

Comment: ok thanks. I think this is the answer but it looks a bit weird so I'll stick with static names for now :)

Comment: Is it possible to use a dynamic variable for a template reference? I want to be able to use steps/test-dev.yml or steps/test-qa.yml that is driven off a UI parameter.